# C# Unit Testing(Nunit) the Main method of a console app?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, console-application

I have a question on unit testing the Main method of a console app. The standard signature is

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
```

I want to be able to test to ensure that only 1 parameter is passed in. If more than one parameter is passed in that i want the test to fail.

I don't think i can mock this with MOQ as its a static method.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need to mock it?  Does it have dependencies that cannot be called?

Comment: Input should be checked at run time inside your main method. Why is this crucial for your unit test?

Comment: Just a note for future readers: The signature can be changed to `static int Main` and I sometimes make use of that return signal to create unit tests

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is nothing to mock in your scenario. Static `Program.Main` is a method just as any other and you test it as such -- by invoking it.

The issue with `static void` method is that you can only verify whether it throws exception or interacts with input argument (or other static members, eventually). Since there is nothing to interact with on `string[]` you can test former case.

However, a more sound approach is to delegate *all* logic contained in `Main` to separate component and test it instead. Not only this allows you to test your input argument handling logic thoroughly but also simplifies `Main` to more or less this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
    bootstrapper.Start(args);
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without re-factoring?

Comment: Can you test that bootstrapper is called correctly? Assume the motivation is code-coverage metrics.

Answer (score 1):

### Integration test

*ProgramTest.cs*

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests;

public class ConsoleTests
{
    [Test]
    public void ProhibitsMoreThanOneArgument()
    {
        var capturedStdOut = CapturedStdOut(() =>
        {
            RunApp(arguments: new string[] { "argument1", "argument2" });
        });

        Assert.AreEqual("Passing two arguments is not supported.", capturedStdOut );
    }

    void RunApp(string[]? arguments = default)
    {
        var entryPoint = typeof(Program).Assembly.EntryPoint!;
        entryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[] { arguments ?? Array.Empty<string>() });
    }

    string CapturedStdOut(Action callback)
    {
        TextWriter originalStdOut = Console.Out;

        using var newStdOut = new StringWriter();
        Console.SetOut(newStdOut);

        callback.Invoke();
        var capturedOutput = newStdOut.ToString();

        Console.SetOut(originalStdOut);

        return capturedOutput;
    }
}
```

### Implementation

*Program.cs*

```
if (args.Length > 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Passing two arguments is not supported.");
}
```